# Use default Spring session when Redis is unavailable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, redis

**Context:** I am trying to use the Spring's Redis session to save session across multiple Tomcats on cloud. But there are some environments where Redis will not be available. I want to configure a way to allow my application to go back to default implementation depending on the environment at runtime.

I am not able to figure the correct way to revert to default spring session configuration when Redis is not available in my environment.

I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I am able to use the Redis session (with its default configuration) when I extended a class as follows:

```
public class RedisHttpSessionApplicationInitializer extends 
    AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

}
```

I tried using the constructor of my `RedisHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` to load the `SpringHttpSessionConfiguration` instead when Redis is not available and followed the docs at 
[SpringHttpSessionConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/config/annotation/web/http/SpringHttpSessionConfiguration.html) and [EnableSpringHttpSession](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/config/annotation/web/http/EnableSpringHttpSession.html).

So I made some changes as follows:

```
public class RedisHttpSessionApplicationInitializer extends 
    AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {
        public RedisHttpSessionApplicationInitializer(){
            super(SpringHttpSessionConfiguration.class);
        }
 }
```

And:

```
@Bean
public SessionRepository<MapSession> sessionRepository() {
    return new MapSessionRepository(new HashMap<>());
}
```

I am still getting error as follows:

```
ERROR 921  [Thread 19] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - 
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined 
in org.springframework.session.config.annotation.web.http.SpringHttpSessionConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 
'springSessionRepositoryFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 
'org.springframework.session.SessionRepository<?>' available: expected 
at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBea
```

Could you suggest me to try anything for my use case? Also, please let me know if you need more information from me.

Comment: @Matheus Lacerda Thanks for correcting grammar

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to work around is by using a `CustomRedisHttpSessionConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRedisHttpSessionConfiguration extends RedisHttpSessionConfiguration {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        if (isRedisPresent()) {
            // Do something
        }else{
            // Do Something else
        }
     }

}
```

Also, to Initialize my application, I used the following:

```
public class RedisHttpSessionApplicationInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        //...
    }
}
```